# Sublime Text 2 viewing a theme's attributes

Tags: themes, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to see all the attributes used in the Sublime Text 2 theme used for PHP. Where can I view the settings?

For example where can I view all of Monokai's attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme
```

and

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/PHP
```

Comment: On Ubuntu (and other linux distros?) you'll find it somewhere like `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`

Answer (score 2):

On Windows7: (note - you'll have to be viewing hidden files/folders to see AppData)

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default\Monokai.tmTheme`

You can copy that file and move it to a new folder like `...\Packages\Users` so that it doesn't get overwritten if there's an update that would change it. I did this for the Twilight theme so I could have a more grey text instead of white for plain text. If you do this, `Preferences` => `Color Scheme` will have two options now. Mouse over User (or whatever you named the folder) and it will have your modified theme.

**Note:** there isn't an explicit set of settings for PHP; the settings seem to apply to all syntax. You'll see tags like `<string>Comment</string>` and a hex value a few lines below that. That will be your color code for comments in any syntax.